# Are there any concerns about bacteria growth in dechlorinated water in a whole house filter system?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-filtration

Do you have to shock your system water if going to be on vacation for a few weeks?

I am just curious if there's any warning or precaution I need to be aware since my system will be designed to reduce the chlorine in the city tap water.

Comment: I live in an area that has no city water. Everyone has a well and nobody treats their water with chlorine. No special precautions need to be taken with water in our house if we go on vacation. Nobody gets sick from drinking their water.

Answer (score 2):

If your system is clean, and the incoming water is clean, there should be no concern. I suppose you could bypass it and flush the pipes if feeling paranoid.

I last shocked my system in 2010 or so. I have an undetectable test result for E coli from 2021 testing. I'm on a well. Bacteria have to get there to become a problem...

In your case, the time of concern would be when the system is first installed, and when you change filters, which are the points where you expose the filtered side of the system to contamination. You'd also have to be concerned if the city supplier has a failure which results in a boil water order, indicating that your incoming water is not clean.

Comment: Ok I was jsut thinking opening and closing fauct/shower during normal use would introduce bacteria someway, but I guess not since the system is primed with water.